# Find the distance to the shore

Tags: geometry

**Problem**

> Let $A,B,$ and $C$ be three points on the edge of a circular chord such that *B* is due west of $C$ and $ABC$ is an equilateral triangle whose side is $86$ meters long. A boy swam from $A$ directly toward $B$. After covering a distance of $x$ meters, he turned and swam westward, reaching the shore after covering a distance of $y$ meters. If $x$ and $y$ are both positive integers, determine $y$.

**Solution**
[image]

**Question**

They say the above equation can be rewritten as $(x+y_1-43)^2+(2y_1)^2 = (43-y_1)^2$, but how is that possible? Are they talking about $x(86-x) = y(x+y)$?

Comment: It is very difficult to follow without a graph.

Comment: @MiguelAtencia Just inscribe an equilateral triangle in a circle.

Comment: You forgot to tell us where the shore is. Is the boy in a circular swimming pool?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are. You can verify it directly by working out the squares, possibly using the fact that $A^2-B^2=(A+B)(A-B).$ But if you want to know how they arrived there in the first place, note that they were trying for a form that had no linear term in $x$, so the existing linear terms $xy$ and $-86x$ had to be incorporated as double products in a complete square.

Comment: If I plug in $y = 2y_1$ into $x(86-x) = y(x+y)$ I don't get what they have.

Comment: Are you sure? Because I do. Have you worked out and simplified the other equality as well?

Comment: You are right, sorry.

Comment: But how do you I recognize to get it in that form?

Comment: That was the second part of my answer. Once you have worked out $y(x+y)-x(86-x)$ you notice that it has two terms that are linear in $x.$ You want to obtain an expression consisting of the square of a term that is linear in $x$ plus one or more terms that do not depend on $x.$ That can be done by "fixing" $a$ in $(x+a)^2$ so that the double product $2ax$ coincides exactly with those linear terms $xy-86x.$ The only choice is to put $a=y/2-86/2$ which is what the authors have done.